# I have a VBA code. How should covert it into VbScript Code

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a VBA code that returns me the cell address of a particular date in an excel column.

VBA Code:-

```
Sub GetDates2()
    Const findDate As Date = #10/1/2020#
    Dim R As Range, C As Range, WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Worksheets("FY2021 Bank txn-stats")
Set R = WS.UsedRange

For Each C In R
    If C.Value2 = CDbl(findDate) Then MsgBox (findDate & " found in " & C.Address)
Next C
End Sub
```

Now I want a VBScript code corresponding to the VBA Code above in which I should able to provide the excel file location and date to find.

I tried by myself but it is not giving any output.

VBScript Code(I tried):-

```
Sub GetDates2()
    Dim R,C,WS,findDate

Set findDate=#10/01/2020#
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oData = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileLocation)
Set WS = oData.Worksheets("FY2021 Bank txn-stats")
Set R = WS.Range("C1:C500").Cells

For Each C In R
    If C.Value = CDbl(findDate) Then MsgBox (findDate & " found in " & C.Address)
Next
End Sub
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: `Set` is for object references, `findDate` is not an object reference, remove the `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

### Get Date Cell Address(es)

- Basically, the first `VBA` solution is written in `VBScript`.
- Note that you could write the second `VBA` solution in `VBScript`, and you could write the `VBScript` solution in `VBA`.

**VBA**

```vb
Option Explicit

' All Occurrences (if not 'Exit For')
Sub GetDatesLoop()
    
    Const wsName As String = "FY2021 Bank txn-stats"
    Const fDate As Date = #10/1/2020#
    Const cCol As String = "C"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(cCol))
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In rg.Cells
            If c.Value = fDate Then ' Works without 'CDbl'.
                MsgBox fDate & " found in " & c.Address
                ' If you want the first occurrence only, use the following:
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    End If

End Sub

' Faster, but First Occurrence Only
Sub GetDatesMatch()
    
    Const wsName As String = "FY2021 Bank txn-stats"
    Const fDate As Date = #10/1/2020#
    Const cCol As String = "C"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(cCol))
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Dim cIndex As Variant
        cIndex = Application.Match(CDbl(fDate), rg, 0) ' Needs 'CDbl'.
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            MsgBox fDate & " found in " & rg.Cells(cIndex).Address
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**VBScript**

- It will open the file in another instance of `Excel`, do the job and close (`Quit`) the instance.
- The workbook is only read from so it doesn't matter if it's already open in another instance of `Excel`. Even `Read-Only` set to `True` is not necessary but 'feels' correct.
- Note this `xlApp.Intersect(...)` (You don't need `Application.` in `VBA`.).
- Adjust the values in the constants section (`FilePath`).

```vb
Option Explicit

GetDatesLoop

Sub GetDatesLoop()
    
    Const FilePath = "F:\Test\Dates.xlsx"
    Const wsName = "FY2021 Bank txn-stats"
    Const fDate = #10/1/2020#
    Const cCol = "C"
    
    Dim xlApp: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'xlApp.Visible = False ' Default. No need to 'show' what's happening.

    Dim wb: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, , True) ' (Read-Only = True)
    Dim ws: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg: Set rg = xlApp.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(cCol))

    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Dim c
        For Each c In rg.Cells
            If c.Value = fDate Then ' Works without 'CDbl'.
                MsgBox fDate & " found in " & c.Address
                ' If you want the first occurrence only, use the following:
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    wb.Close False ' (SaveChanges = False)
    xlApp.Quit
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it still not giving me the output in VBScript. I have a .xlsm file and the date format in this file is dd-MMM-yy. That's why I was using the CDbl function to convert the date into double and then it matches the value in double then it returns the cell address. Can you please provide me the revised VBScript code according to that?

Comment: Still working on my end. The format in `VBA` is `m/d/yyyy` i.e. in your case `#10/1/2020#` means the `1st October 2020`. If you need the `10th January 2020` switch to `#1/10/2020#`.